# How to select an element with attribute based on variable selector which is defined earlier?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

```
var $label = $('label');

//How can I select a `label` using attribute selector, something like below.
$label['data-id=1'].text('some value');
//There is no such a syntax, I am just trying to explain what I need to do.
```

[For more complete example, please visit this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0x7w1y5s/6/)

Comment: Are you asking how to select an element by a `data` attribute?

Comment: Do you want to replace value of label for matching id dynamically?

Comment: This feels like you're trying to find the element with that `data-id` from the collection you found earlier? In which case `$label.filter('[data-id=1]')` should work. Take a look at [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Not exactly. I am asking if I selected a tag in a variable before, then how can I select a div with data attribute, which value, for instance is 1, in case if I do select at the top in the variable, in this case that var is $label.

Comment: Do you mean this: `$('data-id='+$label+').text('some value');`

Comment: @Kalimah even ignoring the syntax problems, that's trying to select a `<data-id />` element. I assume you meant to suggest `$('label[data-id="1"]').text('some value')` instead?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. I think I made a typo. I meant to suggest `$('[data-id=' + $label + ']').text('some value');` The question was a bit unclear so I assumed he wanted a variable data value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `filter` to get the matching id label from `$label` and then set the text value. see below code

```
  var $label = $('label');

  var id = $(this).find('.form-control-data-id').text();
  var val = $(this).find('.form-control').val();
  $label.filter(function(){
    return id == $(this).data('id');
  }).text(val);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/70wqoygv/1/)